# How to make a top arrow on an Electron window?

Tags: css, electron

I'm going off the [Tray Window](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/752) issue on Electron's Github, which shows how to make a window centered on the tray. Some of the screenshots over there show people with a tray window and a top arrow indicating the tray, like [so](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3478693/5566142/3ae16a34-8f43-11e4-873c-7bcd395669e1.png). But I'm only getting something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy7cw.png). Here's the code (main.js):

```
var ids = [];
const {BrowserWindow,app,Tray} = require('electron');
var trayIcon = null;
const TRAY_ARROW_HEIGHT = 50; //px
const WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;

app.on('ready', function() {

  const {screen} = require('electron')

  window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: WINDOW_WIDTH,
    height: 420,
    title: 'Hello World',
    resizable: true,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,
    show: false
  });

  window.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/main.html`);

  window.on('close', function () {
    window = null;
  });

  trayIcon = new Tray('tray.png');

  trayIcon.on('click', function() {

    var cursorPosition = screen.getCursorScreenPoint();

    window.setPosition(cursorPosition.x - WINDOW_WIDTH/2, TRAY_ARROW_HEIGHT);

    window.show();
    window.focus();

  });

  window.on('blur', function() {
    window.hide();
  })

});
```

And main.html:

```
html class="arrow_box">
    <head>
        <style>
            .arrow_box {
                position: relative;
                background: #88b7d5;
                border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
            }
            .arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
                bottom: 100%;
                left: 50%;
                border: solid transparent;
                content: " ";
                height: 0;
                width: 0;
                position: absolute;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            .arrow_box:after {
                border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
                border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
                border-width: 30px;
                margin-left: -30px;
            }
            .arrow_box:before {
                border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
                border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
                border-width: 36px;
                margin-left: -36px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This should have an arrow</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the size of the border on `.arrow-box` to match the `border-width` in `.arrow_box:after` will show the arrow for you.

`.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background: #88b7d5;
  border: 30px solid #c2e1f5;
}`